# Include external php inside Wordpress Header

Tags: php, wordpress, header, include, require

I am trying to do something simple but it won't work.

I have a custom Wordpress header. I need to include external php classes and other stuff. The problem is that if I do that the page breaks, it doesn't work anymore.

This doesn't occur when I try to "require" external php scripts inside page templates. The problem occurs when I include it in the *header*.

To make it shorter, I have:
**header-home.php** (standard wordpress theme header file, which has to include the following file)

**snippets.php** (a php class)

header.home.php is located at /wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/templates...

snippets.php is located at /resources/scripts/snippets.php

Perhaps the header loads something that is not compatible with custom inclusions?

I was able to include an external php file which contains pure html elements. If I try to load custom classes, the page simply breaks. The include filepath is correct, so that's not the problem.

Comment: when you say the page breaks, do you mean you get a blank page or scrambled HTML?

Comment: I get a blank page

Answer (score 0):

All the files that you are going to require, you must do in the file "functions.php" that is in "/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/functions.php", then in the file "header.php" you can instantiate your objects or call functions. For example:

> **Functions.php**

```
<?php
require("./YourClass.php"); 

function getYourClass() {
  $yourClass = new YourClass();
  var_dump($yourClass); //Verify if it returns data and then delete this line
  return $yourClass;
}
```

> **Header.php**

```
getYourClass();//Here it brings the object and shows the output.
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this. Do you happen to know why what I'm doing isn't working? That is what confuses me.

Comment: Check my answer again

Comment: You were extremely clear. I'll proceed as you described! It's weird that requiring stuff directly in the header breaks the whole thing though. Thank you very much, Marcos!

Comment: Remember that wordpress manages its own folder structure and the header and footer files are output files. If you want to show an output of html, you can check this wordpress function: get_template_part () and the example is here: [get_template_part](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/)